# SimpleXML query

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

hi my xml has this structure

```
<articles>
    <article>
    <title></title>
    <text></text>
    <notes>
          <note>
        <code></code>
        <text></text>
    </note>
    <note>
        <code></code>
        <text></text>
      </note>
    </notes>
  </article>

</articles>
```

i have to do this query (sql speaking :) ):
SELECT article WHERE note.code=XXX AND note.text CONTAINS YYY

how can i do that in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Xpath the query language for xml. W3School have a nice tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/

And to use SimpleXML is simple :P:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
$result = $xml->xpath('/articles/article[code=XXX] and /articles/article[text contains(YYY)]');
foreach ($result as $node)
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: well this is my real code with the real and a bit more complex xml structure
$massime= $xml->xpath('//pronuncia[massime/massima/norme/norma[data contains('.$str1.')]] and //pronuncia[massime/massima/norme/norma/numero="'.$num.'"]');

i get the error SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid predicate

Comment: try: $massime= $xml->xpath('//pronuncia[massime/massima/norme/norma[data contains('.$str1.')]] and //pronuncia/massime/massima/norme/norma/[numero="'.$num.'"]'); I freewheeling this and havn't coded xpath in ages so it might be wrong.

Comment: your code still has an error (invalid predicate).

i solved with this. how can i set your answer as accepted?
`$xml->xpath('//pronuncia[massime/massima/norme/norma/data[contains(text(),"'.$str1.'")] and massime/massima/norme/norma/numero="'.$num.'"]');`

Answer (score -1):

If you use SimpleXML you have to iterate over all childrens and then recursive over their children. Look at DOMDocument and getElementsByTagName method.

I think, it is what you are looking for.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: You can use XPath with SimpleXml to achieve this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Missed that. Good to know. I still think that using DOMDocument is easier for such thing (it's similar to javascript dom interface)